# Is it worth to change from jQuery to vueJS an app made with laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

Is it worth to change from jQuery to vueJS an app made with laravel?

This is something that i have been considering for a long time.

How much time does it take to learn it, is there any community about this like jquery?

Comment: Hi, I;m affraid this question is way to broad. However also consider that jQuery and Vue are not really compareble at all.

Comment: _How much time does it take to learn it_ - How long is a piece of string? Way to broad this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate code from jQuery to VueJS part by part. They can work together at some levels. But then at last it will pay back you effort in long term.

I'm working with Laravel and VueJS and they are working together perfectly.

VueJS has pretty shallow learning curve in my opinion (at the beginning) and there are a lot of lessons for basic VueJS. I would suggest you start from here: https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step. I did start here too. My best Laravel teacher.

The community is getting bigger and bigger and it should be comparable to other frameworks soon.